# No reimbursement from grad school for canceled open house flight expense

Tags: graduate-admissions

Expedia and the airline I booked a trans-Atlantic flight with, have told me I cannot get a reimbursement. Only a refund for airline credit for a future flight. I do not need this.

The grad school I was traveling to for the open house (which was canceled obviously) is not reimbursing me because I was given the option for a refund/flight credit.

I have extremely tight funds... this flight's price was highly non-trivial on my budget.

How can I handle this?

Comment: This is a legal issue, not actually an academic one. You can appeal to them or get a lawyer.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, many universities do the same thing to their own employees.

Comment: I don't give legal advice, but I strongly suggest that advice to pay money to a lawyer over a matter that is worth less than what a lawyer charges is highly misguided.

Comment: Why did people vote for "out of scope?"  I could understand voting for "institutional preferences."

Comment: Sorry Lopey Tail, but they probably wouldn't do this unless they ran out of money to pay for reimbursements.  Could you tell us the job title of the person who told you would not be reimbursed?  And the country of the graduate program?

Comment: You say they do not reimburse you, because you were given an option for a refund - but you weren't? Flight credit is not the same thing, as you do not have the money and will have to use it for a flight that's perhaps not even going to happen (company may go bust). BTW, what is Open House?

Comment: @NateEldredge You mean not reimbursing employees for expenses they incurred if the service is not offered? Where (what country) is that?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist IANAL, but is there something like a "Small Claims Court"?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist  grad director for US STEM PhD

Comment: @CaptainEmacs precisely my issue... i would not have bought the ticket if not for the open house (visit day for PhD programs to help those with multiple offers to decide where to attend)

Answer (score 5):

The starting point is probably to respond politely but firmly to the academic in charge of the admissions process, pointing out that you cannot eat a flight credit, and that the grad school's actions have led to a substantial and unexpected hole in your budget. Frame it as a 'moral' obligation rather than a 'legal' one. If you've had significant interactions with any of the professors as part of the applications process, you should cc them on the email.

If you do not get a satisfactory response, you might then escalate matters by emailing the Head of Department/Dean/University President's office. Again, being polite and non-antagonistic but persistent is probably your best option.

If none of this gets you anywhere, your options are probably to involve a lawyer and/or a journalist.

Comment: The dean's office seems the most likely of your suggestions.

Comment: My main concern now is that, I very much intend to attend this school now. I do not know how well arguing over a $300 ticket would go. (Especially considering PhDs are still forced to pay something like $1000 in "fees" a year.)

Comment: @LopeyTall I pay $1600/yr, but I would caution that this may not be a good time to start a PhD if a $300 expense truly blows a hole in your budget. That isn't too say you aren't owed it back though.

Comment: @AzorAhai this phd is funded/tuiton-waived

Comment: @lopey Of course. They still don't pay a ton, though

Comment: If you intend to attend, why did you go for the open house then? Anyway, this changes consideration. Perhaps you can try to be insistive, but be aware that universities have a lot of things to worry now, so you should balance your need of getting your money back now and your expectation of joining that place. That's quite sad, but it is not clear whether you can have both.

Answer (score 5):

The underlying issue is that if the university reimbursed you, you'd essentially have made money. That's because you end up with the university's money *plus the flight credit*. That seems like a good deal for you, and that makes it a bad deal for the university.

In many cases, airlines give you a choice: (i) take the flight credit for a future flight; (ii) cancel the flight and get a part of the cost back, usually the ticket price minus a cancellation or rebooking fee. You want to go with (i) but that didn't work, so try to go with (ii) in which case you can demonstrate a concrete loss of money, namely what you paid up front minus what you got back in the end. That cost is what a reasonable university would reimburse you for.

Comment: the issue here is that the FLIGHT was canceled, not only the event for which I was traveling.
I find it very odd that the airline is not providing reimbursement in this scenario.

Comment: @LopeyTall, did you ask for a refund *before* the airline cancelled the flight?  If so, you might be out of luck.  But if the airline cancelled and offered you the future flight credit, know that most credit card companies will give you a refund if you paid for something but didn't receive it through no fault of your own.

Comment: @RayButterworth really?! i will look into this! cheers